# Should spawn be used in Erlang whenever I have a non dependent asynchronous function?

Tags: erlang

If I have a function that can be executed asynchronously without any dependencies and no other functions require its results directly, should I use spawn ? In my scenario I want to proceed to consume a message queue, so spawning would relif my blocking loop, but if there are other situations where I can distribute function calls as much as possible, will that affect negatively my application ?

Overall, what would be the pros and cons of using Spawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike operating system processes or threads, Erlang processes are very light weight. There is minimal overhead in starting, stopping, and scheduling new processes. You should be able to spawn as many of them as you need (the max per vm is in the hundreds of thousands). The Actor model Erlang implements allows you to think about what is actually happening in parallel and write your programs to express that directly. Avoid complicating your logic with work queues if you can avoid it.

Spawn a process whenever it makes logical sense, and optimize only when you have to.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that come in mind is the size of parameters. They will be copied from your current process to the new one and if the parameters are huge it may be inefficient.

Another problem that may arise is bloating VM with such amount of processes that your system will become irresponsive. You can overcome this problem by using pool of worker processes or special monitor process that will allow to work only limited amount of such processes.

Answer (score 3):

*so spawning would relif my blocking loop*

If you are in the situation that a loop will receive many messages requiring independant actions, don't hesitate and spawn new processes for each message processing, this way you will take advantage of the multicore capabilities (if any) of your computer. As kjw0188 says, the Erlang processes are very light weight and if the system hits the limit of process numbers alive in parallel (with the assumption that you are doing reasonable code) it is more likely that the application is overloading the capability of the node.